# What is the recommended command workflow for keeping my feature branch updated from develop and then eventually merging my changes back to develop

Tags: git, version-control

I know this parts of this question has been asked in various forums, but I can't see the full sequence of commands in one place.

I want to have a feature branch myFeature which is a long-lived branch, say the work takes a couple of weeks. Occasionally I want to merge *from* develop to keep my feature branch up to date. When the feature is complete, I want to merge my branch back to develop. Also note that I want my feature branch to be public. What is the recommended sequence of commands for this?

Is it:

(1) Create my branch:

```
git fetch
git checkout develop
git pull
git checkout -b myFeature
```

(2) Commit some changes to my branch

(3) Push up my branch

```
git push -u origin myFeature
```

(4) Do some more changes to myFeature

(5) Push those changes. (Note: since myFeature is now public, others might commit to it as well.)

```
git fetch
git pull --rebase
git push
```

(6) It's been a few days, I want to merge from develop.

```
git fetch
get merge develop
git push
```

(7) Repeat 6 every few days as needed.

(8) The feature is complete. I want to merge it:

```
git fetch
git checkout develop
git pull
git merge --no-ff myFeature
git push
```

Is this the clearest way, in terms of the commit history of develop?

In particular, will the commits merged from develop in step 6 somehow have an unwelcome effect on the commit history of develop when myFeature is merged back to develop in step 8?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should follow that approch.

1) Create you feature branch from develop

```
git checkout -b my_feature
```

2) Commit some changes

```
// do some changes and commit it
git pull
// resolve conflict if exist and commit
git push origen my_feature
```

3) Every day update your `feature` branch from `develp`

```
git merge develop
// resolve conflict if exist and commit
```

4) Feature completed:

```
git checkout develop
git pull
git merge my_feature
// resolve confict and commit, if exist
git push origen develop
```

**NOTE:** You can do step 3 at the mid of step 2 ( after `git pull` )